# .htaccess using Rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

How do I rewrite http://bruteforce.tv/streams/shinigami
to
http://bruteforce.tv/shinigami
using the .htaccess?

I'm using the Joomla. 3.X CMS. /steams/ is a category of Joomla which cannot be disabled using the admin panel. Thanks in advance!

Original Joomla .htaccess:

```
##
# @package      Joomla
# @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2013 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license      GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that disallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just below RewriteBase put this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^streams/(shinigami)/?$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

If you want to redirect every `streams/*` then use:

```
RewriteRule ^streams/(.*)/?$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: RewriteRule ^streams/shinigami$ /shinigami [L,NC,R]

Comment: @j_mcnally: Its same thing. My code is just reusing string `shinigami` entered in LHS.

Comment: I just used ur last Code anubhava. Now the URL changed to http://bruteforce.tv/shinigami/ but Im getting a 403 Forbitten error msg. Does it need time or something like that?

Comment: You started your question with `How do I rewrite http://bruteforce.tv/streams/shinigami to http://bruteforce.tv/shinigami using the .htaccess` now you're saying that `http://bruteforce.tv/shinigami` doesn't work :) You probably need to explain your problem better

Comment: Sorry Im not used to it. The URL changed perfeclty! Only thing is the page is not displayed anymore. Like it chagned the URL but didnt connent to it. Do you understand what I mean? :-)

Comment: The thing is `http://bruteforce.tv/shinigami/` is throwing a 403 and that is probably because of some Joomla setting. Above code of mine will not be even called for this URI. (I need to be offline now, will check this post in few hours).

Comment: I think its a problem with my webspace. I found a forum thread wich tells me to edit the httpd.conf in confixx. Thing is its using LiveConfig. I hope it will work as well. Just send an email to my host. Lets hope he can find out whats the problem. This is the code to change btw: <Directory "/home/htdocs/webX/html">
AllowOverride All
Options +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
</Directory>